# Break RSpec matcher to multiple lines

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a way to break long RSpec line to two separate lines:

```
expect(....).to
   eq(.....)
```

?

**Update**:

Now I have an error:

> Failure/Error:
>   expect(@query_builder.questions_from_time(@time_to_test)).to
>        ArgumentError:
>          The expect syntax does not support operator matchers, so you must pass a matcher to `#to`.

The error is disappeared if I remove line break

Comment: You can break is as any other Ruby code. What problem do you have? It might be useful to use more brackets to help Ruby parse your code if there are any problems with more white spaces/breaking lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`to` is technically just a method, but the common style is to leave off the parenthesis on the `to` method in rspec. However, it seems the Ruby parser just doesn't realize you're attempting to send an argument to that `to` method if you separate it to a new line without parenthesis.

Any of the following should work…

```
expect(....).
  to eq(.....)
```

or

```
expect(....)
  .to eq(.....)
```

or

```
expect(....).to eq(
  .....
)
```

or

```
expect(
  ....
).to eq(.....)
```

or

```
expect(
  ....
).to eq(
  .....
)
```

I guess the long and short of it is just "don't break before an argument that isn't surrounded by parenthesis". As to which one of these to use — it depends on the particular code. I would do whatever is easiest to read and keeps the line length fairly short.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a backslash at the end of the line to indicate to ruby that the line continues:

```
expect(...).to \
  eq(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this formatting to look cleaner:

```
expect(
  .........
).to eq(...)
```